# Set message delay in jms message header

Tags: spring, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

We have IBM Websphere MQ 8.0 supporting JMS 2.0 .
Is there a way to set the delivery delay for a message, other than using JMS template's set delivery delay?
Specifically, in a message header , like in active MQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSphere MQ 8.0 does support delivery delay.
Here is the official doc page for *[JMS 2.0 delivery delay](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q119200_.htm)*.

Comment: yeah even i went through it. Thanks for the info !

Answer (score -1):

I don't think Websphere MQ supports delayed delivery, but I have not examined the version 8 docs.

I typically implement delayed delivery by storing the logical message in a DB and scheduling the send using a persistent scheduler like Quartz.

Comment: MQ v8.0 *does* support delivery delay and OP specifically asked about that so the answer seems less than helpful.